# Single machine learning algorithm for multiple classes of data : One hot encoder

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

I have data of the following kind:

```
   x1  x2  y
0  0   1  1
1  0   2  2
2  0   3  3
3  0   4  4
4  1   1  4
5  1   2  8
6  1   3  12
7  1   4  16
```

Is it possible to construct a single machine learning algorithm in python/scikit-learn by defining column `x1` in such a way that a simple linear regression should give `predict(x1=0, x2=5) = 5` and `predict(x1=1, x2=5) = 20`. My actual problem has multiple values of `x1`.

To illustrate the problem better: I have the following code with one hot encoder and it doesn't seem to give the accuracy of training the data separately.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Dataframe with x1 = 0 and linear regression gives a slope of 1 as expected

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[{'x1': 0, 'x2': 1, 'y': 1},
                        {'x1': 0, 'x2': 2, 'y': 2},
                        {'x1': 0, 'x2': 3, 'y': 3},
                        {'x1': 0, 'x2': 4, 'y': 4}
                        ],
                  columns=['x1', 'x2', 'y'])

X = df[['x1', 'x2']]
y = df['y']
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
print(reg.predict(np.array([[0, 5]]))) # Output is 5 as expected

# Dataframe with x1 = 1 and linear regression gives a slope of 5 as expected

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[{'x1': 1, 'x2': 1, 'y': 4},
                        {'x1': 1, 'x2': 2, 'y': 8},
                        {'x1': 1, 'x2': 3, 'y': 12},
                        {'x1': 1, 'x2': 4, 'y': 16}
                        ],
                  columns=['x1', 'x2', 'y'])

X = df[['x1', 'x2']]
y = df['y']
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
print(reg.predict(np.array([[1, 5]]))) # Output is 20 as expected 

# Combine the two data frames x1 = 0 and x1 = 1 

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[{'x1': 0, 'x2': 1, 'y': 1},
                        {'x1': 0, 'x2': 2, 'y': 2},
                        {'x1': 0, 'x2': 3, 'y': 3},
                        {'x1': 0, 'x2': 4, 'y': 4},
                        {'x1': 1, 'x2': 1, 'y': 4},
                        {'x1': 1, 'x2': 2, 'y': 8},
                        {'x1': 1, 'x2': 3, 'y': 12},
                        {'x1': 1, 'x2': 4, 'y': 16}
                        ],
                  columns=['x1', 'x2', 'y'])

X = df[['x1', 'x2']]
y = df['y']
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
print(reg.predict(np.array([[0, 5]]))) # Output is 8.75 
print(reg.predict(np.array([[1, 5]]))) # Output is 16.25

# use one hot encoder

df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=["x1"], prefix=["x1"])
X = df[['x1_0', 'x1_1', 'x2']]
y = df['y']
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
print(reg.predict(np.array([[1, 0, 5]]))) # Output is 8.75
print(reg.predict(np.array([[0, 1, 5]]))) # Output is 16.25
```

How can I use pandas and sklearn for the combined data to get the same accuracy using one machine learning model?

Comment: Welcome to `datascience`. This is one good link that may help you: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html

Comment: @rnso Thank you for the link. My issue is not about setting up a simple regression problem using scikit-learn. It is more to do with how to handle a variable like (`x1`) which qualitatively changes the trend of the data. In the example I gave, the ML algorithm must give `slope = 1` when `x1=0` and `slope=4` when `x1=1`. Is that possible to do with a single ML algorithm or breaking up the data into two training sets is the only alternative?

Comment: Probably you need mixed models as on: https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/mixed_linear.html

Comment: You should post some follow-up here. How did you solve your problem?

Comment: If x1 will have only 2 options then you can keep only one column (x1) for joint dataframe. The try to predict for (0,5) and (1,5). Post here the results.

Comment: It gives the same output as using one hot encoder. I edited the example to include that code.  In any case, this is a simple example for my actual problem which has multiple values for `x1` and I need to create the same model for each value of `x1`

Comment: I think in some algorithms you can put more weight for one variable. Search for it.

Comment: Also, some algorithms other than `linear regression` may give more accurate results. Why not try them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is late, but the question got bumped by Community, so...

Your discussion and data suggest that what you want to produce is the model
$$y = (3x_1+1)x_2,$$
but *that is not a linear model* and so linear regression will not find it.  You can try any number of other nonlinear models, the best type depending on your real use-case.  For instance,

1. If you really just want a linear model for each value of $x_1$, then it's probably best just to split the data along $x_1$ as you started with.  You might need to examine your motivation behind wanting just "one machine learning model".
2. You could introduce a new feature, equal to $x_1 x_2$.  This loses some information from option (1) when $x_1$ has more than two values, but it might be suitable.
3. You could use a tree-based model with linear regression done at each leaf, as in  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78563/regression-tree-algorithm-with-linear-regression-models-in-each-leaf .  If the model fitting procedure decides to split only on $x_1$ and regress only on $x_2$, it mostly recovers option (1), though there's no reason to necessarily expect that.

Answer (score 0):

You can have x1 as a categorical variable, convert it to dummy variables (one hot encoder) and then run linear regression (or any other algorithm).

Comment: Thank you. I used one hot encoder and that doesn't seem to give me the answer. I improved the question by providing pseudo-code. Can you please let me know if I did something wrong with the encoder?